# $\int _{-3}^0\:\pi \left(x+1\right)^2dx$ volume of revolution

Tags: calculus

$y = x+1, x = -3$, and $x= 0$

i have the answer $3\pi$ ; but professor marked it wrong, and said it should be $0$.

Sorry this is a short prompt, but...

Can anyone double check?

Comment: What is your axis of revolution?

Comment: If you are asked to calculate a *volume*, it would be really silly to have the answer be zero.

Comment: rotate axis with all real numbers

Comment: rotate region respect to x-axis @DougM

Comment: In that case, I agree with you.  The volume is a double cone.

Comment: If you are truly interested in the volume that is generated by the rotation, then technically, the integral should be split. You should integrate on interval $[-2,0]$ and then $[0,1]$ Reason is because at $x=1$, the line crosses the x-axis. Certainly then, the volume cannot be zero.